# Property does not exist on type 'A' while using user-defined typeguard

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs2, typeguards

I'm using user-defined type guard to check the type of my object, as described [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).
The example presented in docs is very simple and works well, but my problem starts appearing when I use typeguard inside another 'check' function.

I prepared a minimal example of the problem below:

```js
export interface A {
  a: string;
}

export interface B extends A {
  b: string;
  c: string;
}

// check if example has b and c.
export const isB = (example: A | B): example is B => {
  return (<B>example).b !== undefined && (<B>example).c !== undefined;
};

// check if example has b and c and c equals 'foo'.
export const cEqualsFoo = (example: A | B): boolean => {
  return isB(example) && example.c === "foo";
};
```

Im using Vue2, and inside my component, I have a prop defined as follows and I'm using my type guard methods:

```js
x: {
    type: Object as PropType<A> | PropType<B>
}

// later, in the method
if (isB(this.x)) {
    // works!
    console.log(this.x.b);
}

if (cEqualsFoo(this.x)) {
    console.log(this.x.a);
    console.log(this.x.b); // does not work - typescript throws "Property 'b' does not exist on type 'A'.
    console.log(this.x.c); // does not work - typescript throws "Property 'c' does not exist on type 'A'.

}
```

Seem like the `isB` function check works, but the `cEqualsFoo` function doesn't, because it throws the typescript error I pasted above in the commented code section.
This is weird to me, because `cEqualsFoo` function uses `isB` function under the hood.

What causes the issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: TypeScript doesn't propagate narrowing information to outer calls.

Comment: Thanks @vera. Does that mean that I should define `cEqualsFoo` function as a function whose return type is a type predicate? Like this `const cEqualsFoo = (example: A | B): example is B =>`, or what else can I do here?

Comment: Yeah you would have to dupe the type predicate. Alternatively, use `isB(this.x) && cEqualsFoo(this.x)` and remove the `isB` call in `cEqualsFoo`.

Comment: IMO it's better to split the functions into two (the second method). Oversimplification is not always better and this is the perfect example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you could duplicate the type predicate to mirror the usage of `isB` in `cEqualsFoo`,

```
export const cEqualsFoo = (example: A | B): example is B => {
```

a better alternative would be to change `cEqualsFoo` to only take `B`:

```
export const cEqualsFoo = (example: B): boolean => {
  return example.c === "foo";
};
```

so then you have to use `isB` in conjunction with `cEqualsFoo`:

```
if (isB(this.x) && cEqualsFoo(this.x)) {
```